# File permissions on Laravel and Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel-5, file-permissions

I need to upload an image on /public/candidate/1/pictures/

My code is working fine in local, however when I go to prod the image is saved but it doesn't have any permissions.

So, how can I give this only image full permissions?

All my previous folders have full permissions.

Thanks 4 the help!

Comment: Did you give permissions when you creating the dir? use third method in this article http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory

Comment: Yes! All have full permissions except the uploaded image

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `if (Input::hasFile('document_image')) {

            $file = Input::File('document_image');

            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $name = uniqid();

            if(strtolower($extension) != "jpg"){

                Session::flash('error', "The file must have a JPG extension.");

                return Redirect::back();

            }

            $filename = $name . "." . $extension;

            $pathImage = "/candidates/1/picture/";

            $file->move(public_path() . $pathImage, $filename);

        }`

Comment: Try creating directory structure using method that I mentioned in earlier comment before moving file.   `File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775, true)` gives ability create folder structure with given permission recursively

Comment: It throws me a "File exist" error

Comment: wrap it inside `if(File::exist())`